# Já fiz o tour, dá para remover aquele aviso do topo?

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Mesmo já tendo feito o tour do site, continuo vendo o seguinte aviso no topo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não seria o caso de ocultar isso para quem já tem a medalha de "Informado"?

Comment: Aquele aviso é para todo mundo nos primeiros dias

Comment: Ok, acho que consigo conviver com isso por alguns dias :-)