# Como funciona a relação da comunidade do SOpt com a SE Inc.?

Tags: debate, suporte, comunidade

Alguns acontecimentos de ontem, despertaram a dúvida de como a nossa comunidade se relaciona com a empresa/equipe do SE.

Ontem o Gabe (e já deixando claro que o apontado aqui não é em relação à pessoa) que representa mais diretamente a SE perante a comunidade fez o post [Responder sua própria pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422/) e ficaram algumas dúvidas sobre o motivo da postagem e se foi imposição.

Reforça isso, o fato de não haver envolvimento em outras necessidades da comunidade. Algumas mais importantes, outras mais triviais mas que rapidamente poderiam oferecer um feedback e gerenciar expectativas. Alguns pontos onde parece ter sido deliberadamente deixados sem resposta ou apenas ignorados sem a preocupação do feedback.

Vou começar com contrapontos que foram bem resolvido:

- [Mudar favicon para torná-lo um pouco distinto do usado no StackOverflow em inglês](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/22/)

  O simples status-futuro já indicou que [de 6 a 8 semanas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/140010) nós teremos um resultado nessa questão. E em [Como se portar ao perguntar/responder](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/38/) e [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/) o feedback oficial ajudou. Não que precise sempre de um feedback oficial, mas foi importante naquele momento.
- [Já fiz o tour, dá para remover aquele aviso do topo?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/27/)

  Precisamos disso mesmo? Qual o benefício de usuários que já estão no site há dias, tem atividade e visitaram o tour, ficar com esse desvio visual? Alguém acha que alguém vai ficar clicando lá e ver o Tour e desta vez ler direito porque fica aparecendo sem parar? Não seria uma teimosia sem sentido como outra (que falarei mais abaixo)?.
- [Formatação de data no campo Aniversário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/30/) ("Assuntos on-topic" - deletada)

  Qual o status disso? (Nem vou colocar todos bugs que faltam algum feedback e é claro que nem todos precisam de um agora, o problema é que *parece* que 2 ou 3 foram levados em consideração e todos os outros foram ignorados, estamos sem informação p/ saber o que está acontecendo)

  Foi colocado o status-pronto [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/33/podemos-ter-syntax-highlight-nos-codigos-como-no-so). Nada mais foi "dito" em [O Syntax Highlight ainda não funciona para várias linguagens](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66/).
- [Por que recebi a medalha "capelo" no meta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/65/)

  Só a equipe pode responder.
- [Como será tratada uma "guerra de votos" ou "serial downvote" no br.SO?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/90/)

  Não caberia uma resposta definitiva?
- [Sobre questões de escopo amplo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/97/)

  Porque aqui não houve posicionamento oficial? O problema talvez seja o posicionamento ser seletivo.
- [Como nosso site será graduado?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/141/)

  Obviamente considero uma das dúvidas mais importantes que não há resposta.
- [Vote cedo, vote frequentemente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/)

  Não seria interessante destacar algo incentivando o voto? Não precisa ser esse post. O problema da última questão me parece ser mais de falta de votos que indiquem o que é o bom conteúdo do site.
- https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/ ("Assuntos on-topic" - deletada)

  Dá para deletar isso que foi uma tentativa que esbarrou em problemas técnicos?
- [Por que alguns caracteres não funcionam em tags?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/279/)

  Já dá para colocar no site principal também?
- [Disponibilização da API do Stack Exchange para o Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314/)

  Tem algum posicionamento oficial?
- [O que faremos com conteúdo de terceiros postado sem a devida citação?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319/)

  Aqui não cabe uma posição firme oficial de como lidar com esse problema? Me parece ser algo que até extrapola o interessa da comunidade.
- [Beta privado, até quando?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336/)

  O que falta para abrir? Não é nem uma cobrança para abrir ou pedido de prazo, mas um feedback do que está acontecendo.
- [Minha própria pergunta está na fila de moderação e não sai de lá](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339/)

  Bug bem irritante que sequer sabemos se esá sendo considerado.
- [Votos contrários aparentemente sem razão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344/)

  Porque não tivemos uma resposta definitiva sobre esse assunto que a comunidade deu mais importância?

É claro que entendemos que outros trabalhos estão sendo feitos nos bastidores para melhorar a comunidade e que não é necessário informar absolutamente tudo o que está sendo feito. Mas o que está sendo pedido não é algo que toma muito tempo e é visto em outras comunidades.

Algumas dúvidas surgem sobre o processo.

A tradução é muito complicada de ser colocada? Ela está sendo feita? Não dá para ser incremental?

O que é feito com as dúvidas e questionamentos da comunidade postados aqui? Como é o processo de bastidores? Isso é importante para entender, por exemplo, o que vou discutir a seguir. Estaria acontecendo um problema de [telefone sem fio](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telefone_sem_fio_%28brincadeira%29)?

A SE Inc. não tem obrigação de ter transparência no processo decisório, mas quando não há essa transparência, há um custo, como tudo na vida. Não sei se há essa percepção.

Deixei por último o que talvez seja o mais importante: [O domínio do site será br.stackoverflow.com mesmo?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/50/).

Houve uma discordância clara da comunidade aqui. E a equipe não ouviu o que foi pedido. Aí a mesma questão foi levantada no Metão: [Is “stackoverflow em Português” for Brazilians only?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214167/is-stackoverflow-em-portugues-for-brazilians-only) e ela **foi acatada**. Me parece que ocorrido foi que mais pessoas da equipe foram incluídas no processo decisório e uma decisão melhor foi tomada.

Então agora tudo o que não resolver aqui, devemos postar lá no MSO ([futuro MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own))? Ou seja, aqui é para discutir o que é de interesse exclusivo da comunidade e não envolva a equipe SE, e lá é para discutir e requisitar o que a equipe SE precisa fazer?

Não estou fazendo julgamento ou crítica sobre isso, mas o acontecido indicou isso. Aqui nada aconteceu, postado lá, horas foram necessárias para reverter uma decisão importante. A impressão passada é que lá é o foro adequado para conseguir realizar o que a comunidade precisa perante o SE.

Devemos postar em inglês aqui as questões que necessitem da intervenção da equipe? Eles estarão ouvindo?

Precisamos entender melhor como proceder. Muitos aqui já sabem como funciona no SO e outros sites da rede, mas já foi dito, e percebemos, que aqui é diferente. Só não sabemos quais são as diferenças e como devemos lidar com elas.

Comment: Boa pergunta... se quiser pode juntar esta que ainda não está resolvida também: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/78/texto-cortado-na-tela-de-analise-de-edicoes-sugeridas

Comment: Calma, pessoal, hehe! [Have you ever legalized marijuana?](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com.br/2009/04/have-you-ever-legalized-marijuana.html) Lembrem-se que não somos apenas nós que estamos nos adaptando a um site novo -- essa é a primeira experiência da SE num site em língua estrangeira. Dêem um tempinho, as coisas vão se ajeitando.

Answer (score 19):

Antes de mais nada, desculpem pela ausência nas últimas semanas. Uma série de circunstâncias impediu que o site fosse acompanhado da forma como devia, especialmente por se tratar de um período inicial.

Isso expôs algo que sempre nos preocupou, que tem o nome carinhoso de "O que fazer se o Gabe for atropelado por um ônibus?". Não foi isso que aconteceu (dessa vez!), mas o efeito foi similar... Sem entrar em muitos detalhes, toda a equipe de comunidades mantém um olho no site, com ajuda do Google Translate e tenta tomar providências com relação a algo mais grave. Se um dia eu realmente for atropelado por um ônibus, mais providências serão tomadas :D

O período de fim de ano teve muita gente tirando folga, principalmente os devs. Então foi ainda mais complicado manter as demandas do SOPT em dia. Claro que nada disso serve de justificativa, então nós estamos revisando e melhorando esse processo.

Lembrando que caso o pau quebre pra valer e algum de vocês ache que não pode esperar, é só [entrar em contato](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) direto. Eu prometo que as mensagens não vão pro lixo... Sempre tem alguém de olho. Se você puder escrever em inglês, o processo vai ser mais ágil, mas pode mandar em português mesmo que a gente se vira.

Eu não vou responder aqui à todos os tópicos levantados na pergunta, eles tem seu lugar próprio de discussão, mas quanto à URL do site o que aconteceu foi bem mais simples do que algum tipo de favorecimento do MSO.

Quando eu expliquei a razão da URL atual, aquela era a idéia que seria mantida. Entre uma pergunta e a outra nós conversamos e revisamos o plano. Com base principalmente na recepçào da nossa comunidade... Quando a pergunta rolou no MSO, foi colocada a decisão revisada... Não houve uma consideração maior ao problema só porque ele aconteceu no MSO.

Como o Elias disse, essa é a primeira vez que nós abrimos um site em outra língua, portanto nós estamos **constantemente** revendo a forma de lidar com ele. Nós queremos que esse site seja bem sucedido e dê origem à uma comunidade forte em torno dele. A falta de feedback nos últimos dias foi acidental e inesperada e não reflete a forma como vamos lidar com ele.

Comment: Dá para ver que aquele _ônibus_ não machucou muito o @Gabe :) +1

Comment: Deve ter sido um *autocarro*, @Zuul! :)

Comment: Gabe, sobre o feedback, ver também http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/q/426. Como tem muitos bugs de tradução sendo detectados, talvez seja melhor postar esses em inglês, assim você poderia focar nos assuntos/discussões mais importantes e interessantes.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu não tenho uma opinião muito bem formada sobre posts no MSOPT em inglês, por um lado ajuda os devs e o resto do community team, por outro exclui da discussão quem não fala inglês... Mesmo que o assunto seja a tradução de algo, eu não sei se vale a pena. Vou dar uma olhada no tópico

Comment: Não aconteceu nada que precisava de urgência mesmo. Se isso tivesse acontecido, nós iríamos tentar qualquer coisa, postar em inglês aqui e sinalizar, postar no MSO, sei lá. De fato a maioria das perguntas era só p/ "levantar a lebre". Achei que tinha algo acidental atrapalhando o andamento, mas quando você veio, fez um post e não fez mais nada, começou parecer que não era acidental. Só a sugestão para deixar um comentário rápido sobre isso ou pedir para o *staff* escrever algo em inglês mesmo. Bom que está explicado e melhor ainda que foi só uma bicicleta que te atropelou :D

Comment: Eu sou contra, em teoria. Mas se for pra ajudar, eu topo, contanto que os conteúdos sempre sejam disponibilizados nos dois idiomas (a comunidade traduz).

Answer (score 5):

*(update: movi de comentário pra resposta)*

Calma, pessoal! =)

Lembrem-se que não somos apenas nós que estamos nos adaptando a um site novo -- essa é a primeira experiência da SE num site em língua estrangeira.

Dêem um tempinho, as coisas vão se resolvendo.

Note que algo que pareça ser uma questão muito importante para você, não quer dizer que seja para todo mundo.

Se tivermos um pouco mais de paciência, talvez possamos reparar melhor na coisa maravilhosa que está acontecendo -- um site muito bom pra tirar dúvidas de programação no mesmo idioma que a gente aprendeu a ler. :)

**Sugestão de leitura:**

- [Have you ever legalized marijuana?](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com.br/2009/04/have-you-ever-legalized-marijuana.html) (em inglês)
- [Procrastination and The Bikeshed Effect](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/procrastination-and-the-bikeshed-effect.html) (em inglês)

Comment: Justamente por ser um experimento, deveria ter até mais atenção que o normal. Tenho certeza que muitas coisas boas estão sendo feitas nos bastidores, só falta um pouco mais de feedback. Parece que essa é sensação das 10 pessoas que realmente estão ativas aqui. Claro que algumas pessoas estão contentes do jeito que está, outras estão silenciosamente se afastando.